# java name a file using a string plus another letter

Tags: java, file-io

I would like to create several (2) files using a string the user types in.

Example: The user types in "Alpha" and the program will create a file called "alphaa" and another one called "alphaq".
I have this for now

```
b = keb.nextLine(); //b is the user input
try{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (b, true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw){
        out.print("stuff);
        out.print("other stuff");
        out.print("somthing);
}catch (IOException e){}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: It'd be great if you could demonstrate your own attempts at doing this, or places you have looked for help, as random strangers on the internet are unlikely to want to help someone who will not help themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename (incl. extension) that you pass as an argument to the `File` class constructor is simply a string. You can produce it using any string manipulation method.

Having read that, you can simply create a file with the name you want as follows:

```
String s <-- user_input ;
File f = new File(s + "a.dat");
File f2 = new File(s + "q.dat");
```

The above snippet will create two files `alphaa.dat` and `alphaq.dat` if `user_input == alpha`. It's just like concatenating two strings. This is valid for both creating a `File` object as well as a `RandomAccessFile` object.